# How to retrive values when collision occured in HashMap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

How will I get the value associated with the key?

Suppose, my code is written like below:

```
Hashmap hm = new Hashmap();`

hm.put("a","aValue"); // Suppose hashcode created for key "a" is 209

hm.put("b","bValue"); // Here hashcode created for key "b" is 209 as well.
```

Now, I want to retrieve value associated to key `"b"`. I will call `hm.get("b")`. Since, hashmap searches key/value pair based on hashcode of key. Hashmap will find `209` hashcode for key `"b"`. Since, same hashcode is found for key `"a"`, Hashmap may return value `"aValue"` instead of expected value `"bValue"`

So, here is my question, I want to retrieve value associated with key. How will I do that?

Answer (score 8):

`HashMap` knows how to handle multiple keys having the same `hashCode`. As long as the two keys are not equal to each other (using `equals` of the class the keys belong to), `HashMap` can distinguish between them even if they share the same `hashCode`.

When two distinct keys have the same `hashCode`, they are stored in a linked list structure in the map index that corresponds with the `hashCode`. When you search for one of the keys (by calling `get` or `containsKey`), the `HashMap` would locate the map index that corresponds with the the `hashCode` and search the entries in the linked list sequentially, using `equals` to identify the requested key.

Comment: So only hm.get("b") will return bValue, if `a!=b`?

Comment: @Razib  `hm.get("b") will return `bValue` as long as `!a.equals(b)` (note the usage of `equals`).

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I want to retrieve value associated to key "b".

OK.

> I will call hm.get("b").

That's all you have to do.

> Since, hashmap searches key/value pair based on hashcode of key. Hashmap will find 209 hashcode for key "b".

Correct. Or whatever the hashcode for "b" is.

> Since, same hashcode is found for key "a", Hashmap may return value "aValue" instead of expected value "bValue"

No. You are mistaken. It already works correctly. You don't have to worry about it.